# Release pipeline Azure Container Registry & Azure App Services - specify container tag

Tags: azure-devops, tags, azure-web-app-service, containers, release

Using Azure DevOps to build and deploy(release) an container based application. Build and push the image to ACR in the build pipeline, and then a classic Release pipeline to deploy it to Azure App Services.

The build-pipeline pushes the image to ACR with an tag based on $(Build.BuildId).

The Release-pipeline is currently configured to use the :latest version of the image.

I guess it is not good practice to use the :latest tag for production, as you might have multiple builds after your release, making new container images with :latest tag, without necessary wanting to deploy them into production. And as the App Services seems to boot every now and then, and then pull a newer :latest image than the one used when the Release pipeline was executed.

I would like to change this behavior, to rather specify which image the deploy when I create a new release, and that this will be picked up in the App Service task.

How should the Artifact & Stages(task) be configured in order to achieve this?

If I select "Specify at the time of release creation" under the Artifact section, can I refer to this somehow as Tag over in the Deploy to App Service task?

Comment: Not get your latest information, is Krzysztof Madej's workaround helpful for you? If yes, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) which can also benefit for others who has same puzzle with you. Also, feel free to leave comment below if still has any puzzle about it:-)

Answer (score 2):

If you use `$(Build.BuildId)` to set tag then you can use the same value in release pipeline to specify which version should be deployed as it is available.

If you check [Default variables - Primary Artifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#default-variables---primary-artifact) you will find this

```
Build.BuildId   Release.Artifacts.{Primary artifact alias}.BuildId
```

and thus you can use specific tag for which release was triggered.